# Properly animating a plane reflection

Tags: animation, objects, reflection

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but even after several rephrasings I still don't see what I am looking for. I'm also a n00b when it comes to solid modelling, although I have a rudimentary grasp of the basics thanks to the Donut tutorial.

*Problem / Challenge*: I want to animate an object (a ball-and-stick representation of a methane molecule with 4 different substituents, to be precise) being plane reflected to its mirror image. I can *create* the actual mirror image easily enough, but the intermediate steps of atoms and bonds being projected onto a flat plane and then outward again towards their destination locations are proving to be a headscratcher.

Please note that I am not after 'mirroring the animation'; I am after 'animating the mirroring'.

I could calculate the projection onto and outward from the plane by hand of course, but especially the necessary Euler rotations will be extremely tedious. Not to mention that if I change the mirroring plane I can redo the calculations. Just before typing up this message I chanced upon what looked like a geometry node editor which I'm guessing could at least automate the calculations. But perhaps there is a better, more encompassing way of doing what I want.

Ideally I want the motion of the molecule to be such that the original 3D form becomes a 2D projection on the mirroring plane, and then subsequently becoming the mirror 3D form. If that is too difficult to accomplish easily, I'll settle for the individual elements of the molecule remaining 3D objects on the mirroring plane, albeit already scaled and rotated.

Thanks in advance for any pointers, tutorials, and tips.

Comment: Could you illustrate a bit what you're looking for? Using a simple mirror modifier could do?

Comment: [This sort of thing?](https://imgur.com/a/g6h2H0o)